# Which of these interpretations is more accurate?

Tags: casual

I had the [following interaction](https://twitter.com/Sanparo_Z/status/1722406762169663885) on X (formerly Twitter):

> S: 車運転してる時ってなんか聞いてる？
>
> C: 何してもいつも音楽やポッドキャストを聞いている。運転する時はアニソンかポップやクラシックロックかも。
>
> S: ポッドキャストちょいちょい聞くけどポッドキャストってなんぞや〜…？

My question is about the last line. Both Google Translate and DeepL suggested a translation like "I listen to podcasts a lot, but what is a podcast?", which seems unlikely. I feel like it is closer to one of the following:

1. I've heard (the word) podcast a lot, but what actually is it?
2. I listen to podcasts a lot, but when you say podcasts what ones are you referring to?

Which one of these is more likely to be a better translation, and is there a way for me to understand why that's the case? The casual language and dropping of detail is catching me out.

Comment: There is ambiguity in ポッドキャストちょいちょい聞くけど. The speaker might have *heard about* podcasts, or they might have listened to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first half of the sentence in question is ambiguous, but the former is the correct interpretation. って after the second ポッドキャスト is とは or というのは for seeking a definition here.

You can even ask a short question with って like this:

> ポッドキャストって?
>
> Podcast? (What is it?)

ちょいちょい is somewhere between *sometimes* and *often*. It's not *a lot*.

Comment: That was definitely the interpretation I was leaning towards, so thank you for confirming it.